# Problem with jQuery script to change menu when resizing browser using media queries

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a problem with my jQuery code.

I would like that when my window is above 768px my menu shows up and when I resize the window to be below 768px my menu doesn't show. But here either my menu is displayed in both cases or in neither :
when I press the cross (nav__burger) the menu should appear when I am below 768px but not when I am above.

Cordially.

```js
if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && !$('.nav__menu').hasClass('is-open')) {
  $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
} else {
  if ($('.nav__menu').hasClass('is-open')) {
    $('.nav__burger').addClass('is-active');
  }
  $('.nav__burger').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('is-active');
      $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
    } else {
      $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.header .nav__burger {
  height: 37px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span::before {
  transform: translateY(-2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .nav__burger span {
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav__burger span,
.header .nav__burger span::before,
.header .nav__burger span::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.3s;
}

.header .nav__burger span::after,
.header .nav__burger span::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.header .nav__burger span::before {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  top: -6px;
}

.header .nav__burger span::after {
  bottom: -6px;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.header .nav__menu {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background: #e9bf2b;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.header .nav__menu a {
  transition: color 0.2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 700 125% mostra-nuova, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .nav__menu a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #952929;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(13px);
}

.header .nav__menu a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.header .nav__menu>* {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(2n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(3n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(4n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.header .nav__menu.is-open>* {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.header .nav__menu>*+* {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header .nav__burger {
    display: none;
  }
  .header .nav__menu {
    opacity: 0;
    background: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: normal;
    align-items: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: initial;
    right: initial;
  }
  .header .nav__menu a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 87.5%;
  }
  .header .nav__menu>*+* {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="nav__burger">
      <span></span>
    </button>
    <header class="nav">
      <ul class="nav__menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems to okay with little bit of change required but your logic is not correct. When the window is getting `resize` you need to watch for the resize `event` using jQuery.

We can wrap `if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {})` login in a function and call that function on window `resize`.

```
//Resize window
function resize() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
    $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
  } else {
    $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
    $('.nav__burger').removeClass('is-active');
}
}

//watch window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  resize() 
});
```

When the page `loads` you can call `$( document ).ready(function() {})` the same function again to check whether the `innerwidth` is `>= 768` if it is then continue with logic or else remove `is-open` class.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  resize() //load on document ready
})
```

You place your menu toggle `click` function outside the your if anywhere because that will only work then menu toggle is `visible`.

**Live Working Demo:** (Run snippet and click `full screen` and close full screen to see it all working)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resize() //load on document ready
})

//Resize window
function resize() {
  if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
    $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
  } else {
    $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
    $('.nav__burger').removeClass('is-active');
  }
}

//watch window resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  resize()
});

//Click function
$('.nav__burger').on('click', function() {
  // console.log('fdfd')
  if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('is-active');
    $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
  } else {
    $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.header .nav__burger {
  height: 37px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span::before {
  transform: translateY(-2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.header .nav__burger.is-active span::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .nav__burger span {
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav__burger span,
.header .nav__burger span::before,
.header .nav__burger span::after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.3s;
}

.header .nav__burger span::after,
.header .nav__burger span::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.header .nav__burger span::before {
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  top: -6px;
}

.header .nav__burger span::after {
  bottom: -6px;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.header .nav__menu {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background: #e9bf2b;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.header .nav__menu a {
  transition: color 0.2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 700 125% mostra-nuova, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .nav__menu a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #952929;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  transform: translateY(13px);
}

.header .nav__menu a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.header .nav__menu>* {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(2n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(3n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu>*:nth-child(4n) {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.header .nav__menu.is-open {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.header .nav__menu.is-open>* {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.header .nav__menu>*+* {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .header .nav__burger {
    display: none;
  }
  .header .nav__menu {
    opacity: 0;
    background: none;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: normal;
    align-items: normal;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: initial;
    right: initial;
  }
  .header .nav__menu a {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 87.5%;
  }
  .header .nav__menu>*+* {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="nav__burger">
      <span></span>
    </button>
    <header class="nav">
      <ul class="nav__menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you help me for the last part please ?

Comment: @Syniscoborn In the `resize` function you just to need to add this code `if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {` to check if the window is less then 768px and then you can whatever you needed.

Comment: It's when it's `>=768` that i must do the each.

Comment: @Syniscoborn Sorry i am not catching you. I am not sure what you are trying to do now. Looks like its another thing you want to do - can you please post an other question. So that a proper answer can be provided.

Comment: You can see my question on the bottom of this post with the each but i must post another one ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134150/menu-that-is-deleted-when-i-click-on-a-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134150/menu-that-is-deleted-when-i-click-on-a-link)

Comment: Any idea for my link ?

Comment: @Syniscoborn I am not sure why you have decided to un accept my answer on this question. Since the answer i provided is for this question - if i can not help you with [this separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64134150/menu-that-is-deleted-when-i-click-on-a-link) - that does NOT mean you have to un-accept my answer. That's not how stackoverflow works. I helped you where i could with this question.

Comment: @Syniscoborn Its a bit unfair to do that just to be honest. That now how this meant to be. I helped you exactly with the question you posted here :(

Comment: Your solution is not working properly. Indeed, there is a bug when clicking on one of the menu items and resizing it to less than 768px. Don't take me for a dishonest person knowing that you don't know me.

Comment: @Syniscoborn Can you please point out the bug to me (whats exactly happening) ? you are mentioning now after 1 week. Its working exactly you have said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64099118/13669048) you can campare the question and my answer and please let me know the difference - if there is any difference i will happy to fix that  ?

Comment: There may be a bunch of reasons why I'm only responding now. The cross stays closed when I slowly move the window to the right and it's less than 768px. I had not seen this problem before. The menu closes when I enlarge the window but the cross remains closed.

Comment: So you want the `X` and the `menu` to be opened when you are moving the window to the right and it reaches less 768px ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222442/discussion-between-always-helping-and-syniscoborn).

Answer (score 1):

It works but now i would like that when the window is 768px or less and I click on one of the links it will bring me to the right place. Currently, it only goes down but the menu remains open and the cross remains activated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    resize()
});
  
function resize() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
        $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
    } else if ($('.nav__menu').hasClass('is-open')) {
        $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
    }

}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
resize()
});

$('.nav__burger').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');
        $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open');
    } else {
        $('.nav__menu').addClass('is-open');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    }
});

$('.menu-item').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.nav__menu').removeClass('is-open')
        $('.nav__burger').removeClass('is-active');
    })
});
```

I added the last part with the each but it doesn't work properly and makes my menu disappear when I click on a link and in a case where the window is larger than 768px